# Why eclipse doesn't show ViewHolder?

Tags: android, view

I program and handle with `ViewHolder` but When I type `ViewHolder holder;` it's get an error. when I type `ViewHolder` and use Ctrl + Space it doesn't show like we type `View` and User Ctrl + Space. I use ADT 20.0.3

Why eclipse doesn't show ViewHolder?

Comment: Have you actually declared that class somewhere in your code with the right visibility(I guess you know that class doesn't exist in the SDK)?

Comment: check this link http://pastie.org/5107230

Comment: The `ViewHolder` is a pattern for the adapters in Android. You have to declare that class yourself, in your code that class will have a member `ImageView`. Also your `getView` method is not correct.

Comment: did you have tutorial or sample?

Comment: I'll let teoRetik help you as he already answered your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, maybe because `ViewHolder` is not included into android library and just used like a pattern for `AdapterView`s classes, especially?

## Update:

Unfortunately you found the code snippet which just illustrates using of `ViewHolder` without specification of this class. It's content depends on your list item content. For example, if your `ListView` has list items with `TextView` and `ImageView` elements, so your `ViewHolder` should looks like this:

```
static class ViewHolder {
   TextView text;
   ImageView image;
}
```

It is declared inside your custom adapter class and very efficient for acceleration of `ListView` scrolling, because during creating of the next list item - when you use not null `convertView`- you may refer to `convertView`s content through `ViewHolder` which is usually is the tag of `convertView`.